# EOF error with input statement

Tags: python

```
distance = input("Distance travelled: ")
passengers = input("Number of people travelling: ")
extra = (distance - 1)
extraCharge = (extra * 2) 
cost = 3 + extraCharge 

if passengers > 4:
    charge = (cost / 2)
    cost = (cost + charge) 
print("Cost: " + (cost))
```

So this is my code, can't figure out what's wrong with it. Can someone help me? When I run it, it says EOF error on line 1

Comment: How are you running this? With/without shebang? Directly as an argument to `python`?

Comment: Please provide full stack trace.

Comment: Your code has no regard for types. `str`s get arithmetic operations whereas `int`s are trying to be concatenate with `str`s.

Comment: It seems you are using python (2.x) interpreter with a python3 (3.x) source code. Use python3 instead. Otherwise, if you want to use python 2, move from `input` to `raw_input`.

Comment: I was using an online copy. I can't get my one to work.

Comment: I've tried using raw_input and still get the same result

Answer (score -3):

You need to mention integer when you have taken input.

```
distance = int(input("Distance travelled: "))
passengers = int(input("Number of people travelling: "))

extra = (distance - 1)

extraCharge = (extra * 2) 

cost = 3 + extraCharge 

if passengers > 4:
   charge = (cost / 2)

   cost = (cost + charge) 

print("Cost: {}".format(cost))
```

Sample Input :

```
7 for distance
7 for passengers
```

The Output is :

```
Cost: 22.5
```

Comment: The error is regarding EOF (presumably because of wrong choice of interpreter), type-casting has nothing to do with that (and comes later).